# View changeset author in code for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I am writing C# in Visual Studio (2019) and version control is TFS/Azure DevOps.
Is it possible to see who is reported as author (i.e. Changeset information) for a specific function in code? Much like the references-information generated.
I have a vague recollection I have seen this in action some time in the past.
Or is it only available when using git as SC?

[image: Popup information]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? The feature you're referring to is only available in VS Enterprise.

Comment: Oh, I see. Right now I am using Community edition.